# Transfer-encoding header already present error in JMeter HTTP Request

Tags: java, apache, http, http-headers, jmeter

I keep getting the following error in my Response data tab in jmeter:

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:909)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Transfer-encoding header already present
    at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:93)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:109)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:518)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    ... 9 more
```

My test script was created via the JMeter Proxy. The test is sending multipart data (a jpg image) to a REST API resource via a POST. The HTTP Header Manager auto created by the Recording Controller in JMeter has the following:

```
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Accept : application/json
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
```

Any idea why the Response is getting an error?

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/email/v2/client/user/name/loadtest1@test.net/

POST data:
--oYtJU-XXTgMSkyaIrRBYNXw8AfMA2nMQSzJ20bJr--


Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=b3bb843e-dafd-4cc5-8b0b-045c490736f8

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing from HTTP Header Manager the Transfer-Encoding header.

Can you show you Http Request in your Question ? and the Header Manager in it ?

Comment: I tried removing the Transfer-Encoding header and am getting the same error. In the OP I put the Request, the Header Manager is already in the OP.

Comment: So it worked ? can you give more details I am interested, thx

Comment: I needed to remove the Transfer-Encoding header.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the status of the following parameters of the http request which is failing:

   - Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST
   - Browser-compatible headers
2. You don't have any HTTP Header Manager instances elsewhere in you test plan, do you? As if yes it may interfere as HTTP Header Manager's scope isn't limited to one sampler only when it is not added as a child.
3. Your post request details doesn't look like file upload request. Take a look into [Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide to see whether you missed anything important.
4. Never run load generator and application under test on the same machine. Even when developing or debugging your test.